# Permission Error on Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a signup web form to create a user and store information using the UID. I am getting `FIREBASE WARNING: set at /User/4FzbgqXVX8NlbB0pBkDdJeZ9HHe2 failed: permission_denied` when i attempt to create the user data.

My firebase database rules are as follows. Hopefully to ensure that this data is not available to all users, apart from the admin and the user themself

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the function to create the user and the write the data is as follows

```
<script>
function createUser() {
var Result = "true";
var textUser = document.getElementById('userName').value;
var textPassword = document.getElementById('userPassword').value;
var textAccountID = document.getElementById('accountRef').value;
var textDateCreated = document.getElementById('dateCreated').value;
var textDisplayName = document.getElementById('displayName').value;
var UID;

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword).then(function(user){
  console.log('uid',user.uid);//Here if you want you can sign in the user
  UID = user.uid;

  writeUserData(UID, textDisplayName, textAccountID, textDateCreated);

}).catch(function(error) {
    //Handle error
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  return Result = "false";
});

return Result;

}

function writeUserData(userId, displayName, accountID, dateCreated) {
  firebase.database().ref('User/' + userId).set({
  userId:{
    AccountID: accountID,
    Created: dateCreated,
    Name: displayName}
  });

    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
}


</script>
```

does anyone have any ideas how i can negotiate the above problem?

UPDATE

i have changed the requested node to users like this

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).set({
firebase.database().ref('/users' + userId).set({
```

and my rules look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

however im still receiving the following error message relating to permissions

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/bgzolYFgEgY29WYsNEI0vyULXp13 failed: permission_denied
```

I have also tried changing the rules back to the default ones as per below
, however im still getting permission denied

```
// These rules require authentication
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: in your reference you are using the path "User/" while in your rules you are using "/users" those will be considered different paths

Comment: Please be more accurate in tagging. Your question uses JavaScript and does not mention Android, so it should be tagged as such. I will change it for now, but to improve your chances of getting an answer, it is best if you tag correctly straight away.

Comment: Good catch btw @Ymmanuel. I'll vote to close as a typo.

Comment: sorry @FrankvanPuffelen, my bad. Im writing the android equivalent at the minute and mistakenly tagged that instead. i have also updated my question as i'm still getting a permission error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to correct the above problem, but im glad i have worked through it. For those who are also experiencing a similar issue here is the answer

Firstly i was passing the information to the database incorrectly. I was supplying the following:

```
  userId:{
    AccountID: accountID,
    Created: dateCreated,
    Name: displayName}
```

I now supply this:

```
AccountID: accountID,
Created: dateCreated,
Name: displayName
```

i believe the above was causing my permission errors

this worked for some calls but not all so...

Secondly i figured that the firebase calls may be async tasks and as such calling `signOut()` directly after the set command may be causing some of my intermittent results. I correctly added all of the promises and called the `signOut()` and write data functions from within here.

It all appears to work smoothly now

```
<script>
function createUser() {
var Result = "true";
var textUser = document.getElementById('userName').value;
var textPassword = document.getElementById('userPassword').value;
var textAccountID = document.getElementById('accountRef').value;
var textDateCreated = document.getElementById('dateCreated').value;
var textDisplayName = document.getElementById('displayName').value;


firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(textUser, textPassword).then(function(user){
  console.log('uid',user.uid);//Here if you want you can sign in the user
  console.log('success','user added in createUser');  
  writeUserData(user.uid, textDisplayName, textAccountID, textDateCreated);

}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error','Error when creating user');
    //Handle error
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  return Result = "false";
});

return Result;

}

function writeUserData(userId, displayName, accountID, dateCreated) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    AccountID: accountID,
    Created: dateCreated,
    Name: displayName
  }).then(function() {
  console.log('success','Added record in writeUserData');
        signUserOut();

  })
  .catch(function(error) {
  console.log('error','Error in writeUserData');
    //Handle error
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  return Result = "false";

    signUserOut();

});


}

function signUserOut(){
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        console.log('success','signed user out');
      // Sign-out successful.
    }, function(error) {
    console.log('error','error signing out user');
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
      // An error happened.
    });

}


</script>
```

my database rules look like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to all that helped